# mysqli_query return object not resource

Tags: php, mysqli

I will kindly appriciate if someone cant hint me on how to return a resource with mysqli_query and not an object,because whenever i use it with mysqli_field_name or mysql_fetch_row it return me this error "mysql_field_name() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given".And mind you am not really familiar with mysqli methods.Some help will be appriciated.Below here is my code for full details.

```
<?php
    $dns="mysql:dbname=name";
    $username="name";
    $password="";



    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'oysg');


    $export=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM applicant");
    $header = '';
    $data ='';
    // $export = $stmt;

    // extract the field names for header 
    $fields = 25;

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
    {
        $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
        echo $header;
    }
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    // foreach ( $fields2 as $headers )
    // {
    //     $header .=  $headers. "\t";
    //     echo $header;
    // }

    // export data 
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
    {
        $line = '';
        foreach( $row as $value )
        {                                            
            if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
            {
                $value = "\t";
            }
            else
            {
                $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
    }

    $data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

    if ( $data == "" )
    {
        $data = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";                        
    }

    // allow exported file to download forcefully
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xml");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    print "$header\n$data";
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you mixing up `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` extentions? or is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing OOP and procedural.

You're using OOP when you write:

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'oysg');
```

`$con` is now an instance of `mysqli` with member properties and methods.

However, using the syntax like:

```
$export=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM applicant")
```

Is not the OOP way of doing things. Using any `mysqli_*` functions implies your `$con` is the result of:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'oysg');
```

If you want to stick with OOP, I believe you're after the following `mysqli_query` equivalent:

```
$export = $con->query("SELECT * FROM applicant");
```

Where `$export` is now [an instance of `mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).

Using the OOP-style should also help with your extension mix-and-matching, e.g. `mysqli_query` and `mysql_fetch_name` where the latter is missing the `i` in `mysqli`.

Comment: i've made changes,but istill get mysql_field_name() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given.What i want to actually do is export my database to excel.so i need to use the mysql_field_name() to return the field names but it says an object is paased to it not a resource.how do i go about that pls

Comment: @AlofeOluwafemi If you've made changes to use OOP, and you're still using `mysql_field_name` you didn't make enough changes. Assuming `$export` is an instance of `mysqli_result`, then: `$export->fetch_field_direct($i)` instead of `mysql_field_name`. [This is apparent in the documentation of `mysql_field_name`.](http://php.net/mysql_field_name)

Comment: acyually have used $export->fetch_field()->name.but how do i do something like mysql_fetch_row( $export ) using the mysqli class.thanks

Comment: just did this mysqli_fetch_row( $export ).it worked.I really appriciate your help.